# Dynamic object copied from a typed object has a null value

Tags: c#, dynamic, attributes

I was developing a generical restApi class interactor to deal with my company webservices and found something strange..
When I use dynamic type to get things flexible as Json enable I noticed some attributes appear as null, if it's not strange enough when I execute an explicit cast I Got the correct value.
I'm using Json 6.0.4 from Newtonsoft.Json and .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Do you guys know why this kind of issue are happening?

Follow bellow a small code to illustrate what I am talking about, you can see the bug in vars d_type_2 and j_type_2.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("Json4.txt");
        var jsonObject = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

        var JsonObject_1 = jsonObject;
        dynamic JsonObject_2 = jsonObject;


        dynamic d_type_1 = JsonObject_1.Type;
        dynamic d_type_2 = JsonObject_2.Type;

        JTokenType j_type_1 = JsonObject_1.Type;
        JTokenType j_type_2 = JsonObject_2.Type;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code two ways. First I took a json object, parsed it and could reproduce your case. After this I tried with json array, there it correctly returned `Array` for `JsonObject_2.Type`.

This behaviour seemed strange so I digged into Newtonsoft's [source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

When we work with `JsonObject_1` which the library knows is `JObject` type, it returns `.Type` property value as `Object`.
Below is the `Type` property getter in source code for [JObject](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L256)

```
public override JTokenType Type => JTokenType.Object;
```

But with `dynamic` it takes a different path.

Before going there, it is important to know what happens when we do `JValue.Parse(jsonString)`.
If `jsonString` holds a json object, Newtonsoft library extracts the `key,value` pairs from 'jsonString' and stores it in a private `Dictionary`. This will be useful for what I am explaining next.

Now, to work with "dynamic" Newtonsoft makes use of DLR capabilities in .Net. When we try to read any member property of such `dynamic` object,
it goes through [TryGetMember](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L831) method of JObject's `DynamicProxy`.
As per implementation of this method, it only searches in the private dictionary which I refered to above. If property is not found it returns `null`.
`.Type` thus returns null because it is not available in `Dictionary`.

Try below (fun) variant of your code and see what you get in `d_type_1` and `d_type_2` :)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonString = " {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','Type':'value3'} ";
        var jsonObject = JValue.Parse(jsonString);
        var JsonObject_1 = jsonObject;
        dynamic JsonObject_2 = jsonObject;
        
        dynamic d_type_1 = JsonObject_1.Type;
        dynamic d_type_2 = JsonObject_2.Type;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, great explanation, things start to make sense now!
In that case I want to use the objectType from the Object and not a Value from a Key named Type in the private dictionary, do you think is feasible to change or override the getter method to get this property? Or maybe another simpler solution to keep using dynamic.

Comment: Some workaround can be devised for sure but I would suggest to use `dynamic` only if there is no other way.